# Delete the nullable object key if its value is not 'true' practice

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In Angular, if my interface has a nullable boolean property that, as a system developer and maintainer, I know only makes sense when it is set to 'true', is it bad practice to completely remove the object key when its value is anything other than 'true'?

Just to save some browser memory and eventually database space, as the object is being saved there in the form of a JSON string.

```
interface A { id?: boolean, key: string }

obj: A = { id: false, key: 'Name' }

if (!obj.id) { delete obj.id; }
```

Comment: Personally I'm not sure I see the benefit. You will still need a row for your object in your database, so setting that property to `undefined` instead of `false` won't save you much. You will know your architecture better than me though, so may still be valuable for your use case. You could however make your interface A definition slightly more accurate by using `true` instead of `boolean`, e.g. `interface A { id?: true, key: string }` if you're expecting that there will never be a working value of `false` used in your app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, it's not a good practice to remove object keys from an object or modify it's structure during run time, as it'll lead to confusing and unexpected scenarios if you ever use code that assumes the presence of that key.

The amount of space and memory allocation you'll save by doing this is negligible even at scale and is what would be considered preemptive optimization, which is widely criticized in the Software field and is generally considered a bad thing to do.

The amount of optimization you would receive by doing this, would be taken away from the fact that you now have to write additional logic around the fact that sometimes that object key no longer exists.